# Can ftp_fput() accept remote file path?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

Let's say I have following code:

```
$file="http://example.com/path/to/file.zip";
$in = fopen($file, "r");
var_dump($in);             // result - resource(8) of type (stream)

$put = ftp_fput($ftp->getConnectionId(), $file, $in, FTP_BINARY);
var_dump($put);           // result - bool(false)
```

And I am getting following error:

`Warning: ftp_fput(): http://example.com/path/to/file.zip: No such file or directory in /var/www/inc/application.php`

Connection is established correctly, because I can change directory and read files, but problem appears when I want to upload file as above. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `ftp_fput` allows you to define the remote file path & name.

You are attempting to use a URL instead of a path for your second parameter.

It should be like so:

```
$put = ftp_fput($ftp->getConnectionId(), '/path/to/file.zip', $in, FTP_BINARY);
```

Source: http://au.php.net/ftp_fput

Comment: Yes! It is obvious, stupid me ;-) It is quite late here and I'm a bit tired..Thanks for pointing my mistake!